# Counting restricted perfect matchings

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

It is known that counting perfect matchings in bipartite graphs is $\#P$-hard.

Given a complete bipartite graph $G(U \cup V, E)$, where $|U|=|V|=n$ and a perfect matching $M \subset E$, what is the number of perfect matchings $N$ such that $M \cap N= \phi$?

I want to count such restricted matching as a function of $n$.

> Is there a known formula?  If not, what is the best asymptotic lower-bound on the number of restricted matchings?

Comment: This problem is essentially counting [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangements), permutations with no fixed points.

Comment: Please post it as an answer.

Comment: Okay, I've answered it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matchings on the complete bipartite graph you describe are essentially permutations.  Let $U = \{u_1, \ldots, u_n\}, V = \{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$.  Given a complete matching on G, define a permutation $\sigma: \{1,2,\ldots,n\} \rightarrow \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ by $\sigma(i) = j$ when $u_i$ is matched to $v_j$.  It doesn't matter which matching $M$ is, so after reordering we can assume that $u_i$ is matched to $v_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$.  Then the matchings $N$ that are disjoint from $M$ correspond exactly to derangements:  Permutations $\sigma$ with no fixed points, that is, $\sigma(i) \neq i$ for each $i$.  There is a well-known formula for the number of derangements $D(n)$ of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ that can be found with the inclusion-exclusion formula:  $D(n) = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \frac{n!}{i!}$.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the type of answer that I was looking for. BTW, Are you aware of any asymptomatic lower-bound?

Comment: From the Taylor series expansion of $1/e$ we can see that $D(n) \approx n!/e$.  In fact, $D(n)$ is the closest integer to $n!/e$.